# how to enable root user in linux(Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu

In Linux (Ubuntu),I am going through with a lot of problems. In ubuntu, I haven't got any root user. So, I have to apply `sudo` bash at every Instance. I just want to create a root user, from which I can login and have all the privileges.

Comment: Don't log in as root. Ever. Really. The answers below have plenty of reasons why not. I just wanted this warning at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an easy way to do the same using gksu nautilus.

Using this had helped me to obtain root privilages without using any terminal or so.

Answer (score 6):

> **Warning**: Enabling root is not recommended. If possible, you should
>   always try to perform all administrative tasks using sudo. [*as noted in [the referenced page](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/ubuntu-tips-how-to-login-using-su-command-su-gives-authentication-failure-error-message/)*]

In Ubuntu root is present but has no password assigned. All you need to do is issue:

```
sudo passwd root
```

And define a new password for this user.
 [Reference](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/ubuntu-tips-how-to-login-using-su-command-su-gives-authentication-failure-error-message/)

Comment: and from where I can login? Since In the welcome screen It doesn't have a user named root

Comment: If you are going to reference a page that begins with a warning, it's probably a good idea to copy that warning too.

Comment: @Ritzz081 it is explained on thequestion 2 of the link Ive provided you.

Comment: How do I undo this once I don't need it anymore?

Comment: sudo passwd -l root

Answer (score 5):

You need to read the official - [Ubuntu User Guide](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Precise)

**NOTE:** be very careful using root!

- [Why is it bad to run as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root)
- [How to run administrative commands](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/sudo_root.8.html)

To make it clear for your answer:

If you are referring Ubuntu desktop, You don't see the username `root` you will see the username you have been created during the installation:

[image]

If you need to use root privilege on terminal after you login.

You need to use

```
sudo [the command you would like to run]
```

It will ask you your default username password which already has root privilege.

or you can use full root by:

```
sudo su
```

Comment: you can also use `sudo -s`

Comment: @Achu you are wrong,look at the documentatio: By default, the Root account password is locked in Ubuntu. This means that you cannot login as Root directly or use the su command to become the Root user. However, since the Root account physically exists it is still possible to run programs with root-level privileges. This is where sudo comes in - it allows authorized users (normally "Administrative" users; for further information please refer to AddUsersHowto) to run certain programs as Root without having to know the root password
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the man page for sudo again; realize that a valid `sudo` command is:

```
 sudo /bin/tcsh
```

Thus you will get a root shell, thus you really DO NOT need to login as `root`.

Answer (score 1):

- Please edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf, append two lines as the following:
- `greeter-show-manual-login=true`
- `allow-guest=false`
- And then reboot your Ubuntu, you can input any username to login the system, include root user.
  If you do not set root password, please use `sudo passwd` to set new password for root user.